# uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library

Tags: android, admob, android-manifest, google-play-services, android-min-sdk

I am using Android Studio Version 1.2.2.

My project's min sdk is 7 and I want to use google play service which requires min sdk 9 and above. So I use the below to overrideLibrary the library.

Although I am getting the below error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library D:\project_name\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-ads\7.5.0\AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.ads" to force usage

I stuck at this point and can not go ahead. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your app must support minsdkversion = 7?

Comment: @ Yeah IO. Yah.. That i can not change. That is the main issue.

Comment: Google play service requires min sdk version = 9. This means if you use it and your app supports min version = 7, some thing will not work.

Comment: Yes correct. No matter if something is not supported but does not build at least. Even i use overrideLibrary in manifast.xml

Comment: Can you post your gradle file?

Comment: Can not paste all content as it is limited to 143 characters

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.phonestate'
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

Comment: dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81164/discussion-between-yeah-io-and-smeet).

Comment: You can add it to your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to update your `minSdkVersion 7` to `minSdkVersion 9` in your gradle file.

Its just mean that your application must not have minSdkVersion (minimum SDK version) lesser then the library minSdkVersion.

update your gradle file and build project again.

Comment: Where is this? build.gradle - defaultConfig?

Comment: @DanceSC that will be in your app folder.

Comment: I was looking for an exact file / location. When I asked build.gradle -> defaultConfig? I was asking specifically what you were referring to because I have updated multiple minSdkVersions in multiple different files including build.gradle and none of them worked :/

Comment: @DanceSC there may be multiple modules you've added in your project all that modules must have same min sdk as your main app or peoject

Comment: yup that was it, it was in the android manifest to one of the modules, thanks for the help!

Comment: i changed to min sdk 9 but now it cant upload apk to mobile 11-29 14:16:09.585 591-870/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 2586
11-29 14:16:35.100 29161-29161/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
11-29 14:16:35.100 29161-29161/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
11-29 14:16:35.290 168-432/? E/audio_hw_primary: select_devices_signal starting... adev->out_devices 0x2 adev->in_devices 0x0
11-29 14:16:35.340 591-717/? E/InputDispatcher: channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
11-29 14:16:37.192 29184-29184/? E/memtrack: Couldn't loa

Answer (score 1):

Update your build.gradle with this minSdkVersion 14

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sample.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.2"
}
```